# Can't load mongo extension in MAMP

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp

I'm trying to install the php mongo extension in MAMP but it doesn't work.

Here is what I did:

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

And find the extension folder with:

```
php -i | grep extension_dir

extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525 => /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
```

And copy the  mongo.so file in MAMP:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/
```

To finish, I added extension=mongo.so in:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini
```

But even after a MAMP restart, the mongo extension is not loaded in phpinfo().

I also tried to compile the extension with sources but same problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the PHP version to 5.4.4 and the extension is now well loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with MAMP for php 5.5.10 - turns out MAMP has the php.ini files in two different places - /Applications/MAMP/conf/php.5.5.10 and /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf!  It uses the latter, but I was editing the former.  Hope this is helpful to someone else!